# Как взаимодействовать с камерой, используя JS?

Tags: javascript

У меня есть код, с помощью которого я пытаюсь включить камеру по-кнопке и также исключить ее вместе с изменением текста. Ошибок у меня нет, однако она не работает должным образом? Что я делаю не так ли? Спасибо

```
<video id="video" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;"></video>
<button id="button"></button>

let button = document.getElementById('button');
button.addEventListener('click', () => {

button.value = button.pressed ? 'Clicked' : 'Not clicked'
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true}).then(function (stream) {
    let video = document.getElementById('video');
    video.srcObject = stream;
    video.play();
})
})
```

Comment: То есть, когда кнопка нажата текст должен быть "Clicked" а когда отпускаешь "Not Clicked"?

Comment: @ПростаMiha, типу toggle: включено или нет

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно, то проблема в том, что не трэкается состояние кнопки. Если так, то - заведите состояние этой кнопке и меняйте его после клика. Можно решить так:

```js
let button = document.getElementById('button');
let state = "Not clicked";


 button.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
 if(state === "Not clicked"){
 button.innerText = 'Clicked';
 state = 'Clicked';
 }
 else{
  button.innerText = 'Not clicked';
 state = 'Not clicked';
 }
 })
```

```html
<button id="button">Not clicked</button>
```